# in_app_purchase can not open purchase dialog

Tags: flutter, entity-framework, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(storekit_duplicate_product_object, There is a pending transaction for the same product identifier. Please either wait for it to be finished or finish it manuelly usingcompletePurchase to avoid edge cases., {applicationUsername: null, requestData: null, quantity: 1, productIdentifier: premium, simulatesAskToBuyInSandbox: null})

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the in_app_purchase plugin then before starting a new purchase cycle you need to mark all the previous purchase cycles as complete.

you can use a simple for loop to find all the purchase details and mark them as complete.

```
for (var _purchaseDetails in purchaseList) {
    if (_purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
      await _inAppPurchase.completePurchase(_purchaseDetails);
   }
}
```

Remember to use this code before starting the purchase so that no pending purchases are there.

Comment: we do same as you say but still getting error.

Comment: Try printing the list of purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase

Comment: I am also trying this but getting the error occasionally

Comment: How are you getting the `purchaseList`. I am unable to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to trigger the purchase window, you can call finish transaction on open transactions, and it should help.

```
import 'package:in_app_purchase_storekit/store_kit_wrappers.dart';

final transactions = await SKPaymentQueueWrapper().transactions();
for (var transaction in transactions) { 
  await SKPaymentQueueWrapper().finishTransaction(transaction);
}
```